# Send data to database via fetch and subsequently display this data to html page via fetch again without submitting form or refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, json, django

I have a django app. I'm typing a comment in a form and I'm sending it to my database via fetch.

my js code

```
document.getElementById("comment-form").onsubmit = function write_comment(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const sxolio = document.getElementsByName("say")[0].value;

        fetch('/comment', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            say: sxolio
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
    //print result
    console.log(result);
});
```

my views.py

```
@requires_csrf_token
@login_required(login_url = 'login')#redirect when user is not logged in
def comment(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return JsonResponse({"error": "POST request required."}, status=400)
    new_comment = json.loads(request.body)
    say = new_comment.get("say", "")
    user = request.user
    comment = Comment(
        user = user,
        say = say,
        photo = Userimg.objects.get(user = user).image
        )
    comment.save()
    return JsonResponse({"message": "Comment posted."}, status=201)
```

Next thing i wanna do is to display this comment and all the other data from my db, to my html page without refreshing.The moment i push the post button i want the comment to be dispayed. I dont want to update the page with some element.innerHTML = data.

my js code

```
function display_comments() {
    fetch('/all_comments') 
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(all_comments => {
   do some stuff
```

my views.py

```
@login_required(login_url = 'login')#redirect when user is not logged in
def all_comments(request):
    all_comments = Comment.objects.order_by("-date").all()
    print(all_comments[0].serialize())
    return JsonResponse([comment.serialize() for comment in all_comments], safe=False)
```

If i use preventDefault i can see that my db is been updated but i can't retrieve the data.
If i skip prevent default everything works fine but my page is refreshing simultaneously.
Is there any way to do them both without refreshing the page?

Comment: Why not just call your `display_comments` function to pull in the latest comments at the end of the `write_comment` function call?

Comment: I did but all im getting is the data just before i post last comment. For some reason it doesnt return the updated db...

Comment: did you place it inside the result arrow function? Which also looks like it is missing a closing brace.

Comment: yeah, i tryied inside the result and outside, inside the write_comment function and tryied to call it outside but nothing happend. It drives me crazy. I just dont get it how is it possible the db to be updated and cannot retrieve the updated data...
*i have the closing brace but i skipped in the code above..

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that your `all_comments` view request is being made before the `comment` has finished saving to the DB.

It is important that the response for `comment` is completely returned before the fetch to `all_comments` is started. You can accomplish this by doing the following...

```js
function display_comments() {
    fetch('/all_comments') 
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(all_comments => {
        console.log(all_comments);
    });
}

document.getElementById("comment-form").onsubmit = function write_comment(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const sxolio = document.getElementsByName("say")[0].value;

    fetch('/comment', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            say: sxolio
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        // print result
        console.log(result);

        // The request to /comment has finished it is now safe to request all 
        // comments.
        display_comments();
    });
}
```

Comment: its absolutely logical what you're saying and to be honest i had tryied it but it still doesnt work. Thanks so much for your help. At least now i know that it could be done. I just cant get what im doing wrong.